# USB-C Charging via Dongle/Dockingstation on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, usb-c, docking, charging

I'm using the [I-Tec Docking Station / Dongle](https://www.digitec.ch/en/s1/product/i-tec-usb-c-metal-4k-dock-hdmi-100w-thunderbolt-usb-type-a-docking-stations-11128064?supplier=406802) on a Dell Latitude 7480 running Ubuntu 20.04.

The laptop supports charging via USB-C and when plugging in the power supply directly into the laptop it works flawlessly. However, via docking station the laptop is not charging but all other things connected via the docking station (e.g. screen, external hard disc ect.) work. Charging used to work on Windows 10 without any issues before I switched to Ubuntu 20.04. So, I reckon it has something to do with my new operation system rather than that the docking station being broken or not supporting power supply.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You connected the docking station to the power?

Comment: The hub documentation specifically lists the operating systems that are fully compatible, and Ubuntu isn’t on there. You will likely need to search to see if someone has created an open driver for the hub, as 100W power delivery is only done via USB-C when the connected device receives a message from the USB bus and responds accordingly. Otherwise, “bad things” can happen …

Comment: @vanadium Well there's not power supply for the docking station but the charger connected to the docking station is on power supply.

Comment: @matigo Which documentation are you looking at? Cause on the product link above and also according to this one https://i-tec.pro/en/produkt/c31nanodocklanpd-2/ linux based systems should be supported.